# Why does this homemade herbal tea always boil over?

Tags: tea, boiling

I make my own herbal tea with: ginger, turmeric, black pepper, cloves, cinnamon sticks, goji berry, cilantro/parsley, and lemon. I boil the whole in water but for whatever reason I need to be around all the time to avoid a spill-over. It is like having an eye on milk on the fire. Is there any reason why it always spills over?

Comment: just a note, not an answer: you really don't need to boil the water on the highest heat setting - you can lower to a simmer or even less [no bubbles].

Comment: Do you want to know just why, or also (or instead) how to prevent it from happening?